# Set nocompatible not working in vi/vim on 22.04

Tags: command-line, 22.04, vim, vi

I have recently installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 22.04.  When I use vi or vim, it defaults to compatible mode (i.e. arrow keys become ABCD).  I have tried creating **~/.exrc** and **~/.vimrc** with `set nocompatible` as the only entry in the file. After sourcing with **~/.vimrc** and **~/.exrc** it still is in compatibility mode.  I have also tried to set it in vi/vim using `:set nocompatible` and I still do not gain arrow-movement functionality.

I can certainly get around by using **hjkl** but this is really frustrating. Is there another place that is setting is being controlled from?  Is there a better way to set nocompatible elsewhere that I'm not aware.  This really challenges how I perceived **.vimrc** to work, and any help would be greatly appreciated.